# Editing between ArcGIS Desktop and older ArcSDE geodatabase

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, enterprise-geodatabase, editing, arcgis-9.3

We are unable to edit feature classes in an ArcSDE 9.3.1 Versioned GDB using an ArcGIS 10.1 .mxd map. The feature classes are part of a geometric network. Previously we were able to edit feature classes in an ArcSDE 9.3.1 Versioned GDB using an ArcGIS 10.0 .mxd map. It seems that ArcGIS Advanced (ArcInfo level) for 10.1 is incompatible with our 9.3.1 SDE.

Has anyone else experienced this?

---

We are unable to update the 9.3.1 GDB because 1 editor, who is deaf, utilizes special customized tools for performing her work tasks. We are getting a contractor to update these tools to work in 10.1. Then we will convert the GDB to 10.1 and this problem should dissappear.

Yes, we did grant privileges to all editors. The editing problem only occurs if the feature class is part of a geometric network. Otherwise, if the feature class is in a dataset that does not have a geometric network, then editing can be performed. It appears then that ESRI's claim that 10.1 is backwards compatible is invalid for 9.3.1 with geometric networks. We will thus use only ArcGIS 9.3.1 and 10.0 until this specialized conversion is complete.

Comment: Did your GRANT your users editing privileges, sounds like the upgrade removed (or did not re-apply) the correct privileges this can happen more so if the schema has changed.

Answer (score 2):

Why not upgrade your SDE to 10.1. You should keep all ArcGIS at the same version to avoid problems like you're experiencing. It's not just the numbers that change when a new version is released. When a new version is released components are changed, at 10.1 database stuff is managed within the client and not within SDE on the database.
To avoid trouble I highly recommend that you upgrade your ArcGIS suite to the same version.